# python: From dict to df and back to dict again

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, transform

Suppose we have this dict

```
d = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True}
```

With this command, I get this desired Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d.items())

   0      1
0  A   True
1  B  False
2  C   True
```

But when I want to transform back to a dict, I get this:

```
d_again = df.to_dict('records')

[{0: 'A', 1: True}, {0: 'B', 1: False}, {0: 'C', 1: True}]
```

Which its not the same as the first dict d.

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `values` attribute of the dataframe and pass it to `dict`

```py
d_again = dict(df.values)
```

```
{'A': True, 'B': False, 'C': True}
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation would be

```
print(df.set_index(0)[1].to_dict())
```

Which yields

```
{'A': True, 'B': False, 'C': True}
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

dct_in = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct_in.items())
dct_out = df.set_index(0)[1].to_dict()
assert dct_in == dct_out
```